# Generate Hierarchical json in sql server without recursive function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have to build a tree as is in the followed link like this http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033,

I need to generate hierarchical json data in sqlserver database, i have tried using recursive function but as recursive function has max limit32 in sql server i cant contunue with the function, where in i have a very huge  amount of data same as above URL, the tree is complete dynamic and below is my table structure

```sql
CREATE TABLE #dndclasses
(
   id         INT  IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   parent_id  INT,
   name       TEXT
);



INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (1, 0, N'Tom')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (2, 0, N'Josh')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (3, 1, N'Mike')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (4, 1, N'John')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (5, 2, N'Pam')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (6, 2, N'Mary')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (7, 3, N'James')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (8, 3, N'Sam')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (9, 4, N'Simon')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (10, 4, N'QQom')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (11, 4, N'QQosh')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (12, 6, N'QQike')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (13, 6, N'QQohn')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (14, 7, N'QQam')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (15, 7, N'QQary')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (16, 8, N'QQames')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (17, 8, N'QQam')
INSERT [dbo].[dndclasses] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (18, 4, N'QQimon')
```

Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance

Basically i almost need the hierarchical query like in

https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/01/exporting-a-hierarchy-in-json-with-recursive-queries/

But the above is in postgre sql, i have to achieve the same in sql server

**Expected Output**

```js
[{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Tom",
  "Children": [{
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "Mike",
    "Children": [{
      "id": 7,
      "parent_id": 3,
      "name": "James",
      "Children": [{
        "id": 14,
        "parent_id": 7,
        "name": "QQam"
      }, {
        "id": 15,
        "parent_id": 7,
        "name": "QQary"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "parent_id": 3,
      "name": "Sam",
      "Children": [{
        "id": 16,
        "parent_id": 8,
        "name": "QQames"
      }, {
        "id": 17,
        "parent_id": 8,
        "name": "QQam"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "Children": [{
      "id": 9,
      "parent_id": 4,
      "name": "Simon"
    }, {
      "id": 10,
      "parent_id": 4,
      "name": "QQom"
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "parent_id": 4,
      "name": "QQosh"
    }, {
      "id": 18,
      "parent_id": 4,
      "name": "QQimon"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Josh",
  "Children": [{
    "id": 5,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "name": "Pam"
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "name": "Mary",
    "Children": [{
      "id": 12,
      "parent_id": 6,
      "name": "QQike"
    }, {
      "id": 13,
      "parent_id": 6,
      "name": "QQohn"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Check this out!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: Asking us to visit an off-site resource to tell us *how* you want your data presented doesn't help us help you. All the information should be contained in the question itself, with links used as citations or when the information *really* can't be provided in the context of the question (such as pastebins for very large log files, or Paste the Plan for query plans). Include the JSON you want as your results in your question, not somewhere else.

Comment: FWIW, just because you have "big data" doesn't preclude your using a recursive query/algorithm so long as your hierarchy doesn't go too deep. Also, the I wouldn't consider the data at the link you shared to even be particularly large - maybe 100 nodes and a hierarchy depth of 5? That is trivial for this sort of thing.

Comment: In my requirement hierarchy depth is not static it can be more than 100 also

Comment: `OPTON (MAXRECURSION 1000)` lets you bypass the limit

Comment: Post the expected output.

Comment: Added Expected output @SalmanA as requested

Comment: @SalmanA Do you have any solution for this query ?

Answer (score 0):

The recursive approach is the best practice to resolve your requirements; BUT, this query that I share bellow works only with three leves of hierarchy (based on nature of your exampled data). Although, if your tree have more than three nested objects, you need to resort an automatically recursive approach:

```
SELECT Parent.id, Parent.name,
    (SELECT c.id, c.name,
        (SELECT cc.id, cc.name
         FROM #dndclasses cc
         WHERE cc.parent_id = c.id FOR JSON PATH) as ChildOfChilds
     FROM #dndclasses c
     WHERE c.parent_id = Parent.id FOR JSON PATH) as Childs
FROM #dndclasses Parent
WHERE Parent.parent_id = 0 FOR JSON PATH
```

Please, if possible, give us a feed-back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't, as hierarchy level is static but for me hierarchy level is dynamic and can be more than 100 also, so any other solution ?

Comment: But, your question and requeriment in title of this topic ends with `without recursive function`.

Comment: And you add in your question an example of output that you want... Why do you change your requirement???

Comment: I have asked for without recursion because i have already done using recursion and sql has limit of recursion levels as 32 which created a problem for huge data , i dint change my requirement ... i want to generate hierarchial json  in sqlserver